# Merge / concatenate variables together

Tags: ansible

I wish to have a variable defined, however part of it needs to be defined elsewhere. e.g.

```
file1:
var:
 - name: var
   foo: foo

file2:
var:
 - name: var
   bar: bar
```

I then wish to iterate over item.name and print var.foo and var.bar. The scenario is I might want to replace file2 with file3

```
file3:
var:
 - name: var
   bar: baz
```

but still retain the other values

e.g.

env1 = foo = foo bar = bar

env2 = foo = foo bar = baz

I know I can have it like this:

```
file3:
var:
 - name: var
   foo: foo
   bar: baz
```

But it's the duplication of foo = foo which I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Is ``file1`` (2,3) an empty variable? It's not possible ``to iterate over item.name`` because it's not a list.

Comment: No, it's not empty and will never be empty.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *`Is file1 (2,3) an empty variable? "No, it's not empty and will never be empty"`*.

A: The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    file1:
    var:
      - name: var
        foo: foo
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: file1
```

gives

```
  file1: null
```